# jQuery UI Draggable / Resizable - Align To Other Than Top Left

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

Is there any way to switch jQuery UI Draggable / Resizable to use other alignment than from top left, such as bottom right so it does not conflict with DOM objects that are aligned other than top left?

So I can use CSS properties such as right or bottom instead of left or top.

I have a demo and gives result 'auto' from the CSS right position when originally set with Right as 10px and Left unspecified.

In Firefox it gives the calculated pixels whereas Chrome and Internet Explorer gives the result of auto.

Is there any easier way to calculate the pixel value when the result is 'auto'?

https://jsfiddle.net/zerolfc/53apo8z7/

```
<div class="drag"></div>

.drag {
    position: absolute;
    right: 10px;
    top: 10px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: blue;
}

$('.drag').draggable({
    stop: function(e,ui){
        console.log( 'Right position: '+$('.drag').css('right') );
    }
});
```

Comment: Weird, Firefox shows the `right` values, while Chrome doesn't.

Comment: I have just tried Firefox and confirm it does return the pixel value other than auto. In Internet Explorer and Chrome, they return auto.